# systemctl --user vs .config/autostart/*.desktop - when to use which?

Tags: systemd, autostart

I'm developing something similar to [ActivityWatch](https://activitywatch.net/), a daemon that keeps log of what I'm doing and when I was active at my desktop. I would like that to start when I log on and be killed when I log out or restart.

There are basically two approaches to this:

1. Using `systemd --user` by putting a `.service` file in `.config/systemd/user`.
2. Start up with the desktop by putting a `.desktop` file in `~/.config/autostart`.

My question is: Is one of the approaches inherently "better" than the other? Which should I document and which has the better chance of working more places and being more future-proof?

### Details

Here is what I have so far.

**`.config/autostart/actlog.desktop`**:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Actlog
GenericName=Actlog something
Exec=/home/pmorch/work/venvs/test/bin/actlog daemon --monitor-start-only
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
```

This just worked right away.

**`.config/systemd/user/actlog.service`**:

```
[Unit]
Description=ActLog user activity monitoring
After=dbus.service

[Service]
Type=simple
StandardOutput=journal
ExecStart=/home/pmorch/work/venvs/test/bin/actlog daemon --monitor-start-only

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical-session.target
```

I'm honestly having trouble getting the systemd --user approach to work. I'm seeing two problems:

1. The dbus service is indeed started, but I'm seeing dbus errors when my app starts up. Is there some way to tell systemd to start the app when the desktop is fully ready?
2. If I log out, the service is not terminated. And if I log in again, it is not restarted.

The dbus errors I'm seeing are e.g. `The name org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver was not provided by any .service files` - If I sleep 60 seconds in the `.service` file it starts up fine. But that is a hack.

I'm guessing I could get it to work eventually, but these problems do perhaps indicate that systemd --user is not for this use case. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

In general, it would be better to use the autostart method if your application uses or relies on graphical resources.  It should not start the app before the desktop is ready for apps to start.

If you do use systemctl, it may be helpful to use an `after=something.target`.  You can get a list of potential targets with `systemctl --user --type=target`, and the following ones look promising:

```
gnome-session-initialized.target 
gnome-session-initialized.target
gnome-session-manager.target
graphical-session.target
```

Adding the last one to `wants=` will cause your service to load, but it may load before the session is fully up without `after=` and it is unclear to me which of these targets would be best for after=.

If you are having issues polling the screen saver, it might be helpful to put either of these on the after= line

```
org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.ScreensaverProxy.service
org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.ScreensaverProxy.target
```